# google app engine computedProperty: when to use? When not to use?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, app-engine-ndb

When would using a ComputedProperty (ndb) in google app engine give you a distinct advantage over just computing when needed, on the backend (such as in a handler), without the datastore being involved?

Everything I'm reading seems to indicate that it's mostly useless, and would just slow queries down (at least the put operation if nothing else).

Thoughts?

I did see this:

"Note: Use ComputedProperty if the application queries for the computed value. If you just want to use the derived version in Python code, define a regular method or use Python's @property built-in."

but that doesn't really explain any advantage (why query if you can derive?)

Answer (score 3):

The documentation is quite clear on that regard, and i'll cite it again for reference, the [Computed Properties](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/properties#computed) section:

> Note: Use `ComputedProperty` if the application **queries** for the computed value. If you just want to use the derived version in Python code, define a regular method or use Python's `@property` built-in.

When to use it? When you need to query some derived data, it needs to be written to the datastore so it gets indexed.

First example that came to mind: You're already storing the birthday of a user, but also need to filter by actual age, adding a property to derive that value might be the easiest and most efficient solution:

```
age = ndb.ComputedProperty(lambda self: calc_age(self.birthday))
```

Of course you could just have a function that returns the age, but that's only useful *after* you get the entity, can't use it for queries.

Comment: "Of course you could just have a function that returns the age, but that's only useful after you get the entity, can't use it for queries." Yeah, my point: why would it ever be less efficient to just have a function to do that? In this case, why would it ever be less efficient to just have a function that returns the age from that entity? Why bother in the first place with the ComputedProperty?

Comment: It's not about efficiency, if you want to query the data you need to write it to the datastore, that's it.

Comment: But why would you ever want to query it if there's another way to get that information? I think the only thing that makes any sense is if it would some how cause you more queries later if you didn't use a calculatedproperty, but I can't come up with an example where that would be the case

Comment: Another sample is if you have a "popular" ComputedProperty which will create a popularity score based on created date and up votes. Then you wanna query and sort it by popularity. What it says on the usage of computedproperty is the actual usage for it. Very useful.